# Use of "up" in actions

Tags: vocabulary

I'm a brazilian native and I'm curious about the use of `up` in sentences.

For instance:

- set up;
- grow up;
- get up;

What's the real meaning/role of `up` in these phrases? I don't know if my perspective about the problem is different than yours – probably it is –, but it's difficult for me to understand this case of use.

Can someone clarify this question/issue for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Up* has many meanings, and not all of them concern movement in a vertical direction. Your three examples are what are commonly known as phrasal verbs, and they need to be understood as a whole. Even those three can mean different things in different contexts, but *set up* often means ‘establish’, *grow up* often means’ become an adult’ and *get up* often means ‘leave the bed at the start of the day’.